# Keyboard shortcut malfunction in Elementary OS

Tags: gnome3, xbindkeys, elementaryos

I've mapped control + space to pause my music player using xbindkeys

From ~/.xbindkeysrc

```
"mpc pause"
     m:0x4 + c:65
```

However, it doesn't work, but what DOES work is control + space + space.
That is, I have to hit the keybinding twice for it to register.
This is also true for other similar keybindings (eg next, prev, etc)

Does anyone have an clue why this is happening? Or how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the Super key instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> by another key, like <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd>:

- <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (pause)
- <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (resume)

The <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key is the key left of space (and right), like Apple key for apple keybord (of course), Windows key for ...

For the test, I used the Shortcut option under the Tweaks tools (the mpc command is not on my computer system, I used the notify-send to testing the shortcut) :

Screenshot:
[image]

[**How to install Tweak**](http://elementaryos.org/answers/install-elementary-tweak-1)?

Related subject : xmodmap

How to know the keymapping ? :

```
> xmodmap -pke
```

Use the xev command to know the event (as keycode)

```
> xev
```

Note : Maybe my answer is a little bit confuse, hope some hints can help you !

*low*

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, I can get it to work with notify-send like your example, but mpc isn't responding :( I'll continue experimenting, thanks for your input!